# RSpec Array instance_of Argument Matcher

Tags: ruby, rspec

I've got a set of `Task`s (ie command pattern) that get sent to a job scheduler in a list for threading. I want to verify that it's receiving a certain class of `Task` (`CreateTask`, in this example). They're scheduled through `perform_tasks!`, which takes a list of the task objects it's supposed to deal out to threads.

To test this in rspec, I've set up the following:

```
it "should dispatch a Create Task" do
    <... setup ... >

    TaskScheduler.should_receive(:perform_tasks!) do |*args|
        args.pop[0].should be_a CreateTask
    end

    <... invocation ... >
end
```

I've found `match_aray(...)` but I can't seem to figure out how to make it test this nicely, since that tests the contents, not their type. Is there a shorter or better way to test this? Basically, is there something like:

```
TaskScheduler.should_receive(:perform_tasks!).with(array_containing_a(CreateTask))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's an existing matcher for it, but you can write a custom matcher for it easily enough:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :array_of do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    actual.map(&:class).uniq.should =~ Array(expected)
  end
end

TaskScheduler.should_receive(:perform_tasks!).with(array_of(CreateTask))
```

This will make sure that *all* values in the array match the passed type or array of types. If you just want to check that any one value in the array matches your type, that's easy enough as well:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :array_containing_a do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    actual.map(&:class).should include expected
  end
end

TaskScheduler.should_receive(:perform_tasks!).with(array_containing_a(CreateTask))
```

Comment: For anyone coming here recently, `array_including` is part of rspec core now. https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-mocks/RSpec%2FMocks%2FArgumentMatchers:array_including
e.g. `array_including(instance_of(MyClass))`